# React Native Android Build Failure

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I'm currently having this error when I build my react native project using android studio. How do I fix this and remove the duplicates.

```
 Duplicate class com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.CountingMemoryCacheInspector found in modules imagepipeline-base-2.2.0-runtime.jar (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:2.2.0) and stetho-2.0.0-runtime.jar (com.facebook.fresco:stetho:2.0.0)
    Duplicate class com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.CountingMemoryCacheInspector$DumpInfo found in modules imagepipeline-base-2.2.0-runtime.jar (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:2.2.0) and stetho-2.0.0-runtime.jar (com.facebook.fresco:stetho:2.0.0)
    Duplicate class com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.CountingMemoryCacheInspector$DumpInfoEntry found in modules imagepipeline-base-2.2.0-runtime.jar (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:2.2.0) and stetho-2.0.0-runtime.jar (com.facebook.fresco:stetho:2.0.0)
```

Comment: Can you try this one:
https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/660#issuecomment-565119057

Comment: I tried that suggestion but they seem to have a problem with flipper. My thing is having issues with fresco. I'm not sure how to remove the package in the correct format

Comment: Do you have a chance to downgrade to RN 0.61.5?

Comment: i downgraded RN to 0.61.5 but I still have the same error

Comment: Figured out this was an error with the Shoutem UI library. But don't know how to fix it. Posted a follow up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62526519/shoutem-ui-react-native-android-not-building

Comment: Oh :( some ui kits are just pain.

Comment: Could you please share your package.json file here. So I can have the idea which libraries/packages are you using?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same error. Removing the following code from `package.json` the dependencies worked for me:

```
"react-native-photo-view": "github:shoutem/react-native-photo-view#0ffa1481f6b6cb8663cb291b7db1d6644440584d"
```

I'm not really sure why but maybe because that's where the duplication is.

Comment: sure! glad I could help.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar error when I upgraded my React Native project to `0.68.2`.

Solved this by updating the Flipper SDK version. The flipper version was `0.33.1` and changed it to `0.99.0`.

[Credits](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2683#issuecomment-944085698)

Comment: Worked for me on React Native 0.65

Comment: worked for me too updating to 0.65

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be caused by conflicts between Flipper and Fresco. Add this to the app level build.gradle:

```
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}
debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    exclude group:'com.facebook.fresco'
}
```

(FLIPPER_VERSION is defined in gradle.properties as 0.33.1)

Comment: This solution didn't solve my issue. In fact, I got lot of issues after this. Any alternative suggestion?