# Shoutem UI React Native Android Not building

Tags: react-native, shoutem

After manually installing every one of my libraries again, I've noticed that Shoutem UI is throwing an error and breaking my build only for android.

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:7-34
is also present at [me.relex:photodraweeview:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-35 value=(true).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.
```

Following suggestings from online I also tried changing my `android:allowBackup in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml to true` But then that gives me this error

```
Duplicate class com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.CountingMemoryCacheInspector found in modules imagepipeline-base-2.2.0-runtime.jar (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:2.2.0) and stetho-2.0.0-runtime.jar (com.facebook.fresco:stetho:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.CountingMemoryCacheInspector$DumpInfo found in modules imagepipeline-base-2.2.0-runtime.jar (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:2.2.0) and stetho-2.0.0-runtime.jar (com.facebook.fresco:stetho:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.CountingMemoryCacheInspector$DumpInfoEntry found in modules imagepipeline-base-2.2.0-runtime.jar (com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:2.2.0) and stetho-2.0.0-runtime.jar (com.facebook.fresco:stetho:2.0.0)
```

I'm currently using react-native verion: 0.62.2.

These are the other libraries I have installed

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.4.2",
"@react-native-community/picker": "^1.6.5",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.3.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^8.0.7",
"@react-native-firebase/database": "^7.2.4",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^7.2.1",
"@react-native-firebase/storage": "^7.1.5",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.5.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.5.1",
"@shoutem/ui": "^2.0.3",
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "~2.5.6",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.7.1",
"react-native-photo-view": "github:shoutem/react-native-photo-view#0ffa1481f6b6cb8663cb291b7db1d6644440584d",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
"react-native-webview": "9.4.0"
```

},

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I also tried downgrading to RN Version 0.61.5. But was still facing the same issue

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `android:allowBackup="false"` to `android:allowBackup="true"`
in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

After that do

```
cd android (./gradlew clean)
```

and

```
cd .. build apk
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```json
// package.json
"react-native-photo-view": "https://github.com/thanhcuong1990/react-native-photo-view.git"
```

[Source](https://github.com/alwx/react-native-photo-view/issues/207#issuecomment-976947988)